# Function to add many to many field in views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want add a course to the users purchased_course. I am unable to figure out how to add it. The Buy Button Link I added on the Course Listview and Detailview I want that particular course to be added in in the users purchased_course which is many to many field.

My models

```
class Course(models.Model):
...
title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)


class User(AbstractUser):
...
purchased = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True, related_name="buyers")
```

My views
I want the function here

```
@login_required
def puchases_chaeckout(request):
    user=request.user


    return redirect('student-gome-page')
```

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its simple!

```
list_of_courses = user.purchased.all()
```

please read [Django documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: How do i Update or add to it

Comment: @Starwolf please read documents, you can find in it many example

Comment: `user = User.object.get(id = ...)`
`user.purchased.add(new_obj_of_course)`